# Use macros to implement a for statement with its own loop counter in C++

Tags: c++, debugging, c-preprocessor

My requirement is to count the total number of times each for statement in the program loops during the entire runtime of the program, for example:

```
int for_counter_1 = 0;
int for_counter_2 = 0;

void f() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++, for_counter_2++) {
        // ...
    }
}
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++, for_counter_1++) {
        f();
    }
    printf("%d\n", for_counter_1); // should output: 10
    printf("%d\n", for_counter_2); // should output: 100
    
}
```

Since there is a very large number of for loops in my program (some cryptographic algorithms), and I will continue to extend it, I thought about using macros to implement for statements with their own loop counters, like this:

```
#define CONCAT_INNER(a, b) a ## b
#define CONCAT(a, b) CONCAT_INNER(a, b)
#define FOR_COUNTER() CONCAT(for_counter_, __LINE__)
#define for_with_counter(...) \
    static int FOR_COUNTER() = 0; \
    for (__VA_ARGS__, ++FOR_COUNTER())

void f() {
    for_with_counter(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        // ...
    }
}
int main() {
    for_with_counter(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        f();
    }
}
```

It can generate a static counter `for_counter_N` for each for loop, where N represents the line number where the loop is located. I can see the total number of times this loop has occurred in the debugging environment. However, since they are local static variables, I can't print them all out from the main function at the end of the program.

Is there any way to accomplish my purpose? It doesn't have to be a macro, and since I'm using C++, it would be fine if I could use templates and such to get around it. Or if there is a debugging tool that can do this that would also work.

Edit:

I'm sorry I didn't specify, it's not like I didn't think about using map or unordered_map, but since the performance requirements of for loops in my program are quite demanding (since I'm doing some work on cryptographic algorithm optimization), using these data structures would have some performance impact.

Comment: I suggest you begin with something like `std::unordered_map<unsigned, unsigned> counters; /* ... */ counters[1]++; /* ... */ for (auto const& counter : counters) { std::cout << "Counter " << counter.first << " have the value " << counter.second << '\n'; }` Optionally use a `std::array` for the counters, if you know the number of counters that is needed at compile-time. Then wrap in a class.

Comment: You can of course use a map with `std::string` keys, if you want to give the counters more relevant names, instead of just indexes.

Comment: I'd recommend using a function rather than a macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever possible I try to stay away from macros completely.
In this case I would make a type that behaves like an `int` but keeps track on how often it was incremented. For this demo (https://onlinegdb.com/zTJqjvNvE) the reporting is in the destructor (so when the counter goes out of scope).

My line of thought, you don't need to know about the kind of loop just how often something is incremented (this approach will also work for while loops)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename type_t>
class counter_t
{
public:
    explicit counter_t(const std::string name) :
        m_name{ name },
        m_count{ 0ul }
    {
    }

    auto& operator=(const type_t& value)
    {
        m_value = value;
        return *this;
    }

    void operator++()
    {
        m_value++;
        m_count++;
    }

    void operator++(int)
    {
        ++m_value;
        ++m_count;
    }

    operator const type_t& () const
    {
        return m_value;
    }

    operator type_t& ()
    {
        return m_value;
    }

    ~counter_t()
    {
        std::cout << "counter : `" << m_name << "` was incremented " << m_count << " times\n";
    }

private:
    std::string m_name;
    type_t m_value;
    std::size_t m_count;
};

int main()
{
    {
        counter_t<int> counter1{ "counter1" };

        for (counter1 = 1; counter1 < 10; ++counter1)
        {
            if (counter1 > 5) break;
        }
    } // go out of scope and report

    return 1; // can set breakpoint here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a global `map` of counters, with a combination of `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` as a key (e.g. a `std::pair<std::string_view, int>` key).

Comment: There is C++20 [std::source_location::current](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location/current).

Answer (score 2):

Template function seems better:

```
extern std::/*unoredered_*/map<std::string_view, std::size_t> loop_counters; // put definition in cpp file.

// F callable which return false to stop the loop
template <typename F>
void for_with_counter(std::string_view loop_name, int begin, int end, F f) {
    auto& counter = loop_counters[loop_name];
    for (int i = begin; i != end; ++i) {
        ++counter;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<void, decltype(std::invoke(f, i))>) {
             std::invoke(f, i);
        } else {
            if (!std::invoke(f, i)) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With usage

```
for_with_counter("my_loop", 0, 10, [/*..*/](int i){ /* .. */ });
```

Version without providing name explicitly:

```
template <typename F>
void for_with_counter(int begin, int end, F f, std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current()) {
    auto name = std::string(loc.function_name()) + " " + loc.file_name() + ":" + std::to_string(loc.line());
    for_with_counter(name, begin, end, f);
}
```

and change the map to have `std::string` as key.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1q1E4zE9h)

Comment: Why are you always ten minutes ahead of me? Your a thought thief this answer is worth an upvote. But you gotta fix 2 things: 1. Provide one example for breakable and one for unbreakable loops - the former must emulate `continue`. 2. Modify your code to accept a C++20 range instead of integer bounds - integer bounds can simply be emulated using `std::views::iota(st,ed)`. Basically I ask you to implement *profiled* counterparts to `std::ranges::find_if`(breakable loops), and `std::ranges::for_each`(unbreakable loops); the implementation is  forwarding to *unprofiled* `ranges` counterpart.

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd use a global map as some others have suggested, *but* avoid its having significant overhead by creating a wrapper class that initializes a reference to the counter object in its ctor, so from then on, it's just doing a couple of normal increments, just like your code does.

If you really want to, you could even avoid the potential overhead of using a reference in each iteration by creating a local variable, updating it in each iteration, and then adding that to the global in the dtor (but to me that seems like quite a bit of work that's unlikely to accomplish much).

For the typical case where you start each loop from 0 and always increment by 1, you can reduce overhead a bit more by just incrementing your local variable in each loop iteration, and then adding that to the global counter in the dtor.

On one hand, this does potentially add overhead when entering the loop. On the other hand, it potentially reduces the overhead for each iteration of the loop.

Here's a quick bit of proof of concept level code:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <source_location>

class LoopCounterImpl {
    static std::map<int, int> counters;
    int &globalCounter;
    int counter;
public:
    LoopCounterImpl(int initial_val, int loc)
        : counter(initial_val), globalCounter(counters[loc])
    {}

    LoopCounterImpl &operator++() {
        ++counter;
        return *this;
    }

    void operator++(int) { 
        ++counter;
    }

    operator int() const { return counter; }

    static void dump(std::ostream &os = std::cout) {
        os << "\n\n" << __FILE__ << ":\n";
        for (auto const &rec : counters) { 
            os << "line: " << rec.first << ", count: " << rec.second << "\n";
        }
    }

    ~LoopCounterImpl() { globalCounter += counter; }
};

std::map<int, int> LoopCounterImpl::counters;

#define LoopCounter(x) LoopCounterImpl(x, __LINE__)

// And a quick demo of using it:
int main() { 
    for (auto i = LoopCounter(0); i<10; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    for (auto j = LoopCounter(0); j<20; j++) {
        std::cout << j << " ";
    }

    LoopCounterImpl::dump();
}
```

To keep overhead to a minimum, I've written this to have its post-increment operator just return the previous value as an `int`, where it should normally return a copy of `*this` (as a temporary `LoopCounterImpl` object). But in a loop, you normally only execute a `foo++` for the side effect of incrementing the variable, and don't care about the return value. About all you'd be able to do with the temporary LoopCounter would be to retrieve its current value as an `int` anyway, so I've just returned an `int` to minimize overhead.

For the moment, it uses a `LoopCounter` macro to automate retrieving the correct value of `__LINE__`. That, in turn, sort of forces you to use something like `auto foo = LoopCounter(initialValue)`, which doesn't seem terrible to me, but I suppose some might dislike. You could dispense with it if you don't mind something like `LoopCounter x{0, __LINE__}` instead.

Obviously you can also add things like `operator+=`, `-=`, `--`, and so on. I'd guess most of this is pretty obvious from what's already present.

If you were going to put this into a header, you'd want to the `LoopCounter` macro to collect the `__FILE__` along with the `__LINE__`, and use both as the key in the map.